# How to get and store the document ID using a struct

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

I've defined a data structure like so:

```golang
type Person struct {
    Name string `firestore:"name,omitempty"`
}
```

When I query all the documents in a collection I'd like to be able to attach the ID to the documents for later reference, but not necessarily have ID as an attribute stored in Firestore (unless its the only way). In javascript or python this is straightforward as the data structures are dynamic and I can just query the ID post `get()` and add it as a dynamic key/value. `myObj.id = doc.id`

How would I do this with Go?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "cloud.google.com/go/firestore"
    "context"
    "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
    "log"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string `firestore:"name,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    c, err := firestore.NewClient(ctx, "my-project")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v",  err)
    }
    
    var people []Person
    
    iter := c.Collection("people").Documents(ctx)
    for {
        doc, err := iter.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("error: %v",  err)
        }

        var p Person
        err = doc.DataTo(p)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("error: %v",  err)
        }
        // id := doc.Ref.ID
        people = append(people, p)
    }

    fmt.Println(people)
}
```

output, no ID

```
>> [{John Smith}]
```

Comment: One idea I have is to have a second struct which is a `Response` type struct that holds the `Person` struct as well as the reference or ID. e.g.`Document Person, ID string`

Comment: Where are you getting ID from?

Comment: e.g. `Response.ID = doc.Ref.ID`, Then once I assign the data to my `Person` struct I could do `Response.Document = Person`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the firestore struct tags works the same way as the tags in the `encoding/json` package.  So a tag with a value of "-" would mean ignore the field.
So

```
type Person struct {
    ID   int `firestore:"-"`
    Name string `firestore:"name,omitempty"`
}
```

should do the trick.

You can set ID yourself, but the firestore pkg will ignore it when reading/writing data.

Comment: Ahh brilliant, so I could assign `Person.ID = doc.Ref.ID` when getting a document. But when creating a document Firestore will ignore the ID field (empty). I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the firestore document ID on the `Person` type, your struct must have a declared field for it.

[Golang firestore](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/firestore) docs don't mention this explicitly, but since a firestore doc ID is not part of the document fields, the [func (*DocumentSnapshot) DataTo](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#DocumentSnapshot.DataTo) does not populate the ID. Instead, you may get the document ID from the [DocumentRef type](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#DocumentRef) and add it to `Person` yourself.

The doc also states that:

> Note that this client supports struct tags beginning with "firestore:" that work like the tags of the encoding/json package, letting you rename fields, ignore them, or omit their values when empty

Therefore, if you want to omit the ID when marshaling back for firestore, your could use the tag `firestore:"-"`

The `Person` would look like this:

```
type Person struct {
    ID   string `firestore:"-"`
    Name string `firestore:"name,omitempty"`
}
```

inside the loop:

```
var p Person
err := docSnap.DataTo(&p)
if err != nil {
    // handle it
}
p.ID = doc.Ref.ID
```